# Multiple Field Query handling in Lucene

Tags: lucene

I have written an index searcher in Lucene that will search multiple fields in the indexed database.

Actually it takes query as two strings one is say `title` and another is `cityname`.

Now the indexed database has three field: `title, address and city`.

Hit should occur only if the title matches and city name matches. For that purpose I have written the following searcher code using `MultiFieldQuerySearcher` with the help of a post:

```
public void searchdb(String myQuery, String myCity) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Searching in the database ...");
    String[] fields={"title","address","city"};
    MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, fields, new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT));
    parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
    if(!myQuery.toLowerCase().contains(myCity.toLowerCase()))
    {
        myQuery="title:"+myQuery+" "+"address:"+myQuery+" "+myCity+" "+"city:"+myCity;
    }
    Query query=parser.parse(myQuery);
    if (query instanceof BooleanQuery) 
    {
        BooleanClause.Occur[] flags ={BooleanClause.Occur.MUST,BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD,BooleanClause.Occur.MUST};
        BooleanQuery booleanQuery = (BooleanQuery) query;
        BooleanClause[] clauses = booleanQuery.getClauses();
        System.out.println("Query="+booleanQuery.toString()+" and Number of clauses="+clauses.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < clauses.length; i++) 
        {
            clauses[i].setOccur(flags[i]);
        }
        Directory dir=FSDirectory.open(new File("demoIndex"));
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir, true);
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(booleanQuery, 20);
        searcher.close();
        dir.close();
        System.out.println("Number of hits="+hits.totalHits);
    }
}
```

But it is not running properly.

For example if the query is "Pizza Hut" and city is "Mumbai", I want "Pizza Hut" to be searched only in title field of the database and Mumbai only in city field of the database.

But it is finding "Hut" also in the city field of the database as the output of the statement **booleanQuery.toString()** is coming as "**+title:pizza +(title:hut city:hut) +city:mumbai**".

As a result in the for loop it is giving index outOfBound error.

I am new to Lucene. So I am asking for help to fix the problem.

Comment: could you please share your code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We use MultiFieldQueryParser only when we want to search the **same keyword(s)** in multiple fields.

To handle your use case, it is simpler that you already have references to city-keyword and title-keyword separately. Try using following code.

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT);
// city query
QueryParser cityQP = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "city", analyzer);
Query cityQuery = cityQP.parse(myCity);

// title query
QueryParser titleQP = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "title", analyzer);
Query titleQuery = titleQP.parse(myQuery);

// final query
BooleanQuery finalQuery = new BooleanQuery();
finalQuery.add(cityQuery, Occur.MUST); // MUST implies that the keyword must occur.
finalQuery.add(titleQuery, Occur.MUST); // Using all "MUST" occurs is equivalent to "AND" operator.
```

Comment: But Sir there is one problem. In my index there is an entry of which title is "Pizza Hut" and city is "Mumbai". When I am querying the index with title "Pizza" and city "MUmbai", the number of hits turns out to be 0. But it should be one according to my understanding as both the terms are present in their corresponding fields. Can you please explain?

Comment: 1) make sure that you are using the same Analyzer while indexing and querying.--- 2) please print the final query to the output and paste it here.---3) Use Luke to examine your Index. It is damn simple to use. It is a GUI tool to explore and inspect the Lucene Index. Use Luke to check whether the Index contains what you expect.--- BTW, no more "sir" please.. :)

Comment: Final Query is : +city:mumbai +title:pizza. And yes I have used StandardAnalyzer() both during indexing and querying. Yes I have installed LukeAll. No index city name i.e. Mumbai is not being lowercased but in query the city name is being lowercased. Probably that's why the number of hits is becoming zero. But how it can be possible? I have used same analyzer in both the cases.

Comment: Actually at first I have done the city field at the index as NOT_ANALYZED. So in index it was not lowercased and even after rectifying that I forgot to run the indexer again.Instead I kept running the searcher again and again so in the Luke I was seeing the city field not as lowercased. That was the cause of mismatch. Sorry for my mistake.