# Ignite TextQueries on multiple fields

Tags: lucene, ignite

I have the following object:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SearchItem implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    @QueryTextField
    private String description;
    @QueryTextField
    private String brand;
}
```

As you can see I have two fileds enabled with the lucene index. Im confused now how to create the `TextQuery` to search only for a specific field or for both fields. I want to be able to make text searches in the brand field or the descritption field or in both. There is an ignite example showing how to create a `TextQuery`

```
private static void textQuery() {
    IgniteCache<Long, Person> cache = Ignition.ignite().cache(PERSON_CACHE);

    //  Query for all people with "Master Degree" in their resumes.
    QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<Long, Person>> masters =
        cache.query(new TextQuery<Long, Person>(Person.class, "Master"));

    // Query for all people with "Bachelor Degree" in their resumes.
    QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<Long, Person>> bachelors =
        cache.query(new TextQuery<Long, Person>(Person.class, "Bachelor"));

    print("Following people have 'Master Degree' in their resumes: ", masters.getAll());
    print("Following people have 'Bachelor Degree' in their resumes: ", bachelors.getAll());
}
```

But this example is only showing that I have to pass in the class and the search string. How can I define for which field of the class the search should be performed, when I have more then one field annotated with `@QueryTextField`?

Example search string:

```
description = ?, brand = ?
```

Comment: Ignite use Lucene with StandardAnalyzer. Have you tried to use standard syntax [1]?
AFAIK, there can be a bug and field name case (upper or lower) matters.

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728569/multiple-field-query-handling-in-lucene

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use query syntax from Apache Lucene: https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

If it does not work with your field names, I would recommend using names in uppercase instead.